# URL routing and directory redirects

Tags: php, apache, url-routing, slim

Consider the following lines of code used with a PHP framework (Slim Framework v2.0.0):

```
$app->get( '/bootstrap/(:page/?)', function ( $page = NULL ) use ( $app ) {
    if ( $page == NULL ) {
        $page = 'index';
    }
    $app->render( 'bootstrap-tests/' . $page . '.tpl' );
});
```

Running it on XAMPP works like expected:

/bootstrap redirects to /bootstrap/

/bootstrap/ works fine

/bootstrap/css-tests works fine

Now, running the exact same code on the production server, `/bootstrap` ceases to work (no more redirect to /bootstrap/) and 404s instead.

The production server is a Linux server. I've looked into .htaccess directives there (in order to compare them to XAMPP's) but do not see anything special about redirects.

I'm not certain whether this is a framework thing or an Apache thing. Any feedback from someone a little more experienced than I am with frameworks and URL routing is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your development environment should match production. Otherwise, you might as well develop in production. You're only introducing a can of worms by not making them the same. Look into Virtualbox. Using Vagrant for Virtual Box, you could spin up a VM within minutes with little effort.